# I am not able to import all vm in hyperv

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

When importing the VM from hyper-v server not allow to import all VM?
New server 2016 is installed and tried to import the all VM but not allowed.

Comment: actual error messages would be helpful

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: I installed server 2016 on new machine and tried to import all VM from old server but when selecting the VM there is no option to select the all VM. It allows only one VM at a time?

Comment: Edit it into the question, it should be self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's is correct the importing through the console only allows one vm at a time to be imported. have your tried using powershell to import the VMs?